# Element Ids gets replaced by Angular Ids in Selenium python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a Selenium script for testing some functionality. When I login to a site, its  html/ element ids are like below,

```
<td class="gwt-MenuItem" id="admin_menu" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">Administration</td>

<td class="gwt-MenuItem" id="supervisor_id" role="menuitem">Supervisor Interface</td></tr>
```

However, after some time, it changes to angular ids like below,

```
<a href="#" dropdown-toggle="" ng-if="leaf.subtree" class="ng-scope dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span translate="MENU.ADMINISTRATION.MENU" translate-default="Administration" class="ng-scope">Administration</span>
                </a>
```

I've put the `WebDriverWait` to wait till the element is found on the page. But, I get `TimeoutException()` exception. When code stops execution, I came to know that if I click on a home button manually, page gets refreshed and all code starts working again. So, I put the `driver.refresh()` and clicked on home button as well, but no luck.

Comment: Is _click on a home button_ part of your usecase? What are the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: Because the site you are automating is made in angular JS so you do one thing instead of using id you can use xpath relative/absolute then there will be no issued becuase only once the site is loaded after that only content updated page not loaded hence its all works dynamically without refreshing or loading new page its getting new data and id not works in angular

Comment: can you share the site url which you are working on?

Comment: @DebanjanB, That's not a usecase. When code stopped execution, I just clicked on a home button manually and then code started working again. Manual steps would be: Just click on a dropdown `admin_menu`, select another option and then click on a button.